# Retrieve values from mongodb using nodejs in AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lambda

Hi I tried to list the data's from mongodb collection and it's working fine but I need that in lambda function so I converted into lambda function as below but it showing null in the output. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const models = async()=>{

mongoose.connect('----------',{useNewUrlParser:true,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})

const wavicle = mongoose.model('Datasetlist',{Dataset:[{id:Number,dataset:String,parameter: 
[{name:String}]}]})

const me = new wavicle({Dataset:[{id:1,dataset:'Daily Food Report',parameter:[{name:'StoreName'}, 
{name:'Dates'},{name:'TransDesc'},{name:'Amount'},{name:'credit'},{name:'total'}]}]})

me.save().then(()=>{
console.log(me)
}).catch((e)=>{
console.log(e)
})

const main = async(event)=>{
console.log('Event:',event)
return models()
}

exports.handler = main
```

Comment: `models()` doesn't return anything. did you mean to `return me.save()`

Comment: yeah tried using return me.save() it shows the error.                                                        
 {
  "errorMessage": "2020-07-08T04:47:01.379Z 028fad37-82b0-451c-a97b-977e8b28c49d Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Comment: Thanks for your help Cody. Now my program running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here the answer for my question. I used return me.save to return the output

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const models=()=>{

mongoose.connect('---', 
{useNewUrlParser:true,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})

const wavicle = mongoose.model('Datasetlist',{Dataset: 
[{id:Number,dataset:String,parameter:[{name:String}]}]})

const me = new wavicle({Dataset:[{id:1,dataset:'Daily Food Report',parameter: 
[{name:'StoreName'},{name:'Dates'},{name:'TransDesc'},{name:'Amount'},{name:'credit'}, 
{name:'total'}]}]})

return me.save()
}

const main = async(event)=>{
console.log('EVENT:',event)
return models()
}

exports.handler = main
```